# JQuery UI Dialog with callback in button action fails second dialog open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-callback

this seems like a common topic, but I haven't seen anyone post this particular version.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#somebutton").click(function() {
       $.get("someurl", function(data){
          $("#PartsDialogDiv").html(data);
          $("#PartsDialogDiv").dialog("open");
       });
    });


   $("#PartsDialogDiv").dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 600,
           resizable: false,
           modal: true,
           buttons: {
               "Use Part": function() {
                   $.get("someurl", function(data){
                       $("#AnotherDIV").html(data);
                   });
                   $(this).dialog("close");
               },
               "Cancel": function () {
                   $(this).dialog("close");
               }
           }
     });
});
</script>
<div id="PartsDialogDiv"></div>
<div id="AnotherDIV"></div>
```

What happens when I press the button that calls the .dialog("open") after doing the "Use Part" button action is it fails to open.  In fact, it states that:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I have a feeling that the callback on the first press of "Use Part" fails to keep the dailog setting on the PartsDialogDiv and it no longer knows that the div can have that jquery UI method called on it.

With it all wrapped in a $(document).ready(), I am unsure how to handle reinitializing that div to a dialog without putting it within the "Use Part" button function.

Has anybody experienced this and have any good tips or advice on how to handle this?

Thank you in advance!

This is MVC3, but not entirely sure it's relevant.

ANSWER (since I cannot answer my own question until 8 hours after this is posted):
I managed to resolve it.  Jen and George Cummins both led me to this conclusion that my partial view was bad.

In my partial view I have these scripts included:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"
       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
```

They were autogenerated (or I blindly included them for some reason) and are unneeded.  I removed them and everything works as intended.

Thank you so much for your time everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding the context correctly. Can you post the code/click event that calls .dialog("open"); ? Also, calling .dialog("close"); doesn't destroy the DOM element nor destroys any instance of the dialog widget on that element.

Comment: added additional code. and I know what you mean by dialog("close") doesn't destroy the DOM. But if I remove the callback, it works fine. If I have the callback in the button action, it gives that error and I am assuming the callback removes the dialog element. Or something.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is altering "#PartsDialogDiv" when the "Use Part" button click occurs. We would need to see the code in the place of "// Do something" to be sure, but you can examine that code and alter it as necessary. Specifically, look for calls to .destroy() or .disable().

Comment: I was just thinking this might be the issue.  Here, I will update the question to include some additional details that may help clarify it more.

Comment: Agreed. This is a common issue when trying to help someone. If they give crippled/censored code, it makes it difficult for us to help, especially if the problem is within the crippled part of the code. I can relate though, I'm under a strict CDA at work, so when I seek help, I can't paste too much information. But in this case, it's essential, because what you have there is valid code.. so the issue must be within the // do something area.

Comment: Too true.  Added some generic code to represent that better.  Sorry for not including it in the first place.

Comment: Even with the updated code, I do not see anything that would cause this issue.

Comment: I mentioned that I am using MVC3.  Would saying that the "data" in the success being a partial view make any difference?  As far as I know, that is just the html script returned.
Other than that, I am at a loss.  Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML after the data is returned? If you have Firefox, you can install the Web Developer Toolbar (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and use the "View Generated Source" option to see what is being inserted. If the inserted data includes Javascript (not just plain HTML) or if the HTML includes another element with id="PartsDialogDiv", we may be able to identify the problem.

Comment: I confirmed that there is no javascript being passed back (but there is a "form" declaration included).  Also, no other elements with id="PartsDialogDiv".

Comment: found the problem.  it's listed in the OP.  thanks for helping!